# Wrong paths in pydev debugger:

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have Python from Microsoft package  in VS Code.
When I run some Python Code, I have errors:

```
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: threading.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: C:\Users\abukreev\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: genericpath.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: ntpath.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: runpy.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: pkgutil.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: urllib\parse.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: queue.py
```

Python on my laptop in `C:\Users\abukreev\Documents\Python367\.` 
But pydev await it in `C:\Users\abukreev\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages` 
How can I change the `pydev` settings ?

Comment: I just looked at the details of this extension. It says that the PyDev Debugger integration is a planned feature (soon). Could this be the reason for the errors that you see? I'm just using the built-in Python debugger and it works wonderfully well

Comment: Possible pyc corruption? `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete` or whatever the Windows equivalent is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I meet the same problem. I reinstall python using installer, not zip file.

Python3.7.6 download link is 
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.6/python-3.7.6-amd64.exe

Comment: Can you add what the difference is? Also, according to [the official Download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/) the latest version is 3.8.2 – why not use that page (which always contains a link to the latest version)?

Comment: An explanation of the cause could be more useful than the flat solution.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem of the extention itself. However you can ensure that the environment variable called `PYTHONPATH` is pointing to your python folder: `C:\Users\abukreev\Documents\Python367\` and `C:\Users\abukreev\Documents\Python367\lib`.

The `PYTHONPATH` variable tells the system where to find the python modules. If there isn't any `PYTHONPATH` variable in your environment, you should add it yourself.

Read here for further explanation: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_environment.htm